# delete all text after the nth occurance of a whitespace

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I used this snippet to make line breaks inside text. how can I delete the text behind the nth whitespace completely?

```
var str:String = ("This is just a test string").replace(/(( [^ ]+){2}) /, "$1\n");
```

regards

Comment: What do you mean by "completely"?

Comment: You want to replace two or more whitespaces with a single white space and a line break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works using regex `(([^ ]* ){2}).*` and replace pattern `$1`:

```js
function removeAfterNthSpace() {
  var nth = parseInt($("#num").val());
  var regEx = new RegExp("(([^ ]* ){" + nth + "}).*", "g")
  var str = ("This is just a test string").replace(regEx, "$1");
  console.log(str);
}

$('#num').change(removeAfterNthSpace);

removeAfterNthSpace();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="num" value="2" />
```

See it [working on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4FBzna/1).